# How do I get all the options of a field?

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 7, we are using the following code.

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```

What can we use in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal 8.9.x still has the [`options_allowed_values()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21options%21options.module/function/options_allowed_values/8.9.x) (a function implemented in the *Options* module). If the field uses a selection, check box, or a radio button widget, you could use the following code. The same function is still implemented in Drupal 9.3.x, the latest Drupal version under development, at the time I am posting this answer.

```php
$field_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('entity', 'bundle');
if (isset($field_definitions['field'])) {
    $allowed_options = options_allowed_values($field_definitions['field']->getFieldStorageDefinition());
}
```

Replace `'entity'` with the entity type ID (for example, `'node'` for nodes), `'bundle'` with the bundle machine name (for example, `'article'` for Article nodes), and `'field'` with the field machine name.

Keep in mind that this code requires the *Options* module; the module using the code I shown should declare its dependency from it.

Using `options_allowed_values()` has the benefit that, if the field has a function returning the allowed values, that function is called. The following is the code used by `options_allowed_values()` to achieve that.

```php
if (!isset($allowed_values[$cache_id])) {
  $function = $definition->getSetting('allowed_values_function');
  $cacheable = TRUE;
  if (!empty($function)) {
    $values = $function($definition, $entity, $cacheable);
  }
  else {
    $values = $definition->getSetting('allowed_values');
  }
  if ($cacheable) {
    $allowed_values[$cache_id] = $values;
  }
  else {
    return $values;
  }
}
```

Using `options_allowed_values()` also allows to cache the allowed values. In this way, calling `options_allowed_values()` for the same field (and same entity type) multiple times has a minimal impact on performance.

`options_allowed_values()` is defined also in [Drupal 9.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21options%21options.module/function/options_allowed_values/9.4.x) and [Drupal 10.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21options%21options.module/function/options_allowed_values/10.0.x).

Answer (score 4):

To get list of allowed values of field of select list try with:

```
    $options_array = [];
    $field_name = 'field_name';
    $definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('custom_entity_name', 'bundle');

    if (isset($definitions[$field_name])) {
      $options_array = $definitions[$field_name]->getSetting('allowed_values');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try directly from field:

```php
    $allowedVals = $entity->get('field_name')->getSettings()['allowed_values'];
```

Comment: I believe we can say `$entity->get('field_name')->getSetting('allowed_values')` (Drupal 9)